# How to stop 'causing' an element to overflow while using window.pageYOffSet and switch case to change the background-color at given number of pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The goal is that when I scroll down, the `<body>`'s `background-color` changes at every `500px`.**

I've search all over the internet, but don't understand what's happening yet. Please, take a look at the code. But according to Mozilla Firefox Browser, **the `body` element is causing the an element to overflow**

[image]

I've tried using `overflow: hidden` in CSS selecting `body`, also tried with `html`, but the scroll bar just disappears.

I'm a beginner level learner.  *It's supposed to be correct, since it's from a teacher's coding.* Thank you for your time and help. **UPDATE:** It was my mistake by transcribing.

All the answers solved this issue. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CHALLENGES</title>
        <style>
        
            body {
                height: 3000px;
            };

            .one {
                background-color: beige;
                transition: all 3s;
            };

            .two {
                background-color: blueviolet;
                transition: all 3s;
            };

            .three {
                background-color: coral;
                transition: all 3s;
            };

            .four {
                background-color: cornflowerblue;
                transition: all 3s;
            };

            .five {
                background-color: darkgoldenrod;
                transition: all 3s;
            };
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="one">
        
        <h1>Javascript Event Challenges: Challenge 29</h1>
        <p>Scroll Down!</p>

        <script>

            var pageTop;
            var bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");

            window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

                pageTop = window.pageYOffSet;

                switch(true) {
                    case pageTop < 500: bodyTag.className = "one"; break;
                    case pageTop < 1000: bodyTag.className = "two"; break;
                    case pageTop < 1500: bodyTag.className = "three"; break;
                    case pageTop < 2000: bodyTag.className = "four"; break;
                    default: bodyTag.className = "five";
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not functioning properly, because of a spelling error in the 'Offset' :

```
pageTop = window.pageYOffSet;
```

It should be

```
pageTop = window.pageYOffset;
```

It only returns undefined. Since the 'pageYOffSet' is also an alias for 'scrollY', you can use that instead :

```
 pageTop = window.scrollY;
```

The colors are not working because you are using a ";" at the end of every CSS query. Remove those as well and it will work.

Comment: Huge thanks! it worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

1. `window.pageYOffSet` should be `window.pageYOffset`.
2. Remove all the semicolons after the CSS classes in your `<style>` element as they are not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

Test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rb0jh3s/)

try setting `pageTop = window.scrollY;`

also remove the `;` from the css code

```js
var pageTop;
var bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
    pageTop = window.scrollY;
    switch(true) {
        case pageTop < 500: bodyTag.className = "one"; break;
        case pageTop < 1000: bodyTag.className = "two"; break;
        case pageTop < 1500: bodyTag.className = "three"; break;
        case pageTop < 2000: bodyTag.className = "four"; break;
        default: bodyTag.className = "five";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 3000px;
    display:block;
}

.one {
    background-color: beige;
    transition: all 3s;
}

.two {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    transition: all 3s;
}

.three {
    background-color: coral;
    transition: all 3s;
}

.four {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    transition: all 3s;
}

.five {
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CHALLENGES</title>
    </head>
    <body class="one">
        
        <h1>Javascript Event Challenges: Challenge 29</h1>
        <p>Scroll Down!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```